# How do I bind /dev/ttys2 to a port on android emulator?

Tags: android

I am trying to bind /dev/ttys2 to a port on the Android Emulator but I dont know how to. Help is appreciated. I am creating a java application that will connect to a port on the emulator and write data to it and I want the data to be dumped into /dev/ttys2